# Java Calendar define day and time range in the week to compare against

Tags: java, time, calendar

I need to define different periods in the week.
I then need to pass a series of Calendar objects to see which period these Calendar objects correspond to.

e.g.
Period1:

```
    Mon 12:00-15:00
    Tue 14:00-17:00
```

Period2:

```
    Wed,Thu 09:00-17:00
```

Period3:

```
    Thur 17:00-24:00
    Fri  00:00-24:00
```

What is the best way to define these periods in code to pass in calendar objects to see which one if any they correspond to?

Comment: can you explain your periods please?!

Comment: these are the time range within the particular days in a similar analogy to weekday or weekends

Comment: This will help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547995/how-do-you-format-a-date-range-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Always favour the [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes (or [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the [ThreeTen backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) if you aren't on Java 8 yet). See [this article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) for the 'why'.

I would use a [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) and two [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html)s

```
class WeekPeriod
{
    private final DayOfWeek day;
    private final LocalTime start;
    private final LocalTime end;

    //constructor and methods
}
```

Combine these into three `Set<WeekPeriod>`s to represent your three examples.

Comment: Good answer. Prefer to receive your times to check as `ZonedDateTime` or `LocalDateTime`. Extract day of week and time of day through `getDayOfWeek()` and `toLocalTime()` and compare to the fields of each `WeekPeriod` object. If you cannot avoid `Calendar` objects, make sure you get `GregorianCalendar` and convert using [GregorianCalendar.toZonedDateTime()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#toZonedDateTime--).

Comment: I think  Duration will be better here with DayOfWeek  apart from whats is laready mentioned. A Duration measures an amount of time using time-based values.

Comment: @Amit A `Duration` doesn’t tell you whether the period began at `09:00` or at `14:00`. You may use a start time and a `Duration` in combination of course. Which to prefer depends on the concrete situation and requirements.

Comment: @OleV.V. Right. I did consider a `LocalTime` and a `Duration` but it seemed more confusing. You can extract a `Duration` from two `LocalTime`s simply enough anyway (and if that becomes a performance problem, memo it).

Answer (score 1):

### Java 7 and ThreeTen Backport

[Michael’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50504991/5772882) is good. I’d just like to supply a few details. Since you mentioned in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50488461/java-timezone-update-by-double-values#comment87993169_50489980) that you are using Java 7, I present code for Java 7.

First, the date-time classes that Michael is using, are not built into Java 7, but have been backported. So get the ThreeTen Backport that he mentions and import the date-time classes from the `org.threeten.bp` package:

```
import org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils;
import org.threeten.bp.DayOfWeek;
import org.threeten.bp.LocalTime;
import org.threeten.bp.ZoneId;
import org.threeten.bp.ZonedDateTime;
```

Then add the following method to Michael’s `WeekPeriod` class:

```
public boolean isInPeriod(ZonedDateTime dateTime) {
    DayOfWeek dowToCheck = dateTime.getDayOfWeek();
    LocalTime timeToCheck = dateTime.toLocalTime();
    return dowToCheck.equals(day)
            && ! timeToCheck.isBefore(start)
            && timeToCheck.isBefore(end);
}
```

If you prefer the parameter to be a `LocalDateTime` or an `OffsetDateTime`, just change it, the code is the same. You can overload the method, of course, to accept all three types.

If you cannot avoid getting `Calendar` objects, write one or two overloaded methods for them too. Convert your `Calendar` to a `ZonedDateTime` and call the above method. It‘s a bit more straightforward if your `Calendar` is a `GregorianCalendar`, which it probably is:

```
public boolean isInPeriod(GregorianCalendar cal) {
    return isInPeriod(DateTimeUtils.toZonedDateTime(cal));
}
```

If it isn’t:

```
public boolean isInPeriod(Calendar cal) {
    ZoneId zone = DateTimeUtils.toZoneId(cal.getTimeZone());
    return isInPeriod(DateTimeUtils.toInstant(cal).atZone(zone));
}
```

All of the above works in Java 7 and in Java 6 too. I have tested on jdk1.7.0_79.

### Java 8 and later

For anyone reading along and using Java 8 or later:

- Import the date-time classes from the `java.time` package instead (don’t use ThreeTen Backport).
- Instead of using `DateTimeUtils` convert using the methods that have been built into `Calendar` and `GregorianCalendar` from Java 8. For the `GregorianCalendar` use `cal.toZonedDateTime()`. For other `Calendar` subclasses use `cal.getTimeZone().toZoneId()` and then `cal.toInstant()`.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.